# How can I parse my 2d array with a cover array to find a character?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

Basically, my assignment is to store a message inside a 2-dimensional array and that message comes with a cover message that is a series of dashes and O's that needs to be "placed over" the original message at a specific coordinate (row, column) to reveal a message. I am currently stuck on how to "place" the cover message over the original message to decode the text. My friends have told me to parse the cover over the message and write a series of `if`-statements that say "if there is an o, take that dimension in the two dimensional array and add it to a message variable".

This is the message:

> "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness. That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed, --That whenever any Form of Government becomes destructive of these ends, it is the Right of the People to alter or to abolish it, and to institute new Government, laying its foundation on such principles and organizing its powers in such form, as to them shall seem most likely to affect their Safety and Happiness."

And this is the cover message:

```
-O------O-----O-------------------------
--O----O--------------------O------O----
------O---O-----------------------------
----------------------O--------------O--
------------------------------O-----O---
-----------------------------------O----
-------O---------------------O----------
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:** So far I have filled a 2d array with the message and a 2d array with the cover message. The cover message is supposed to fit over the original message array starting at `[2][5]`. Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class M {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inFile = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(inFile);

        int lines;
        lines = scanFile.nextInt();

        String message = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++)
            message += scanFile.nextLine();

        message = message.replace(" ", "");
        message = message.replace(",", "");
        message = message.replace("-", "");

        String[][] am = new String[lines][59];

        fill2DArray(am, message);
        print2DArray(am);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(am).replace("], ", "]\n"));

        String r = scanFile.nextLine();
        r = r.replace(",", "");
        String ro = r.substring(0,1);
        String co = r.substring(1);

        int crow = Integer.parseInt(ro);
        int ccol = Integer.parseInt(co);

        int cline = scanFile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(cline);

        String cover = "";
        for (int u = 0; u <= cline; u++)
            cover += scanFile.nextLine();

        String[][] cm = new String[cline][40];

        fill(cm, cover);
        print2DArray(cm);
    }

    public static void fill2DArray(String[][] arr2D,String message)
    {
        int counterLetters = 0;

        for(int i =0;i<arr2D.length;i++) //arr.2D.length gives row length
        {
            for(int j = 0;j<arr2D[i].length;j++)//arr2D[].length gives column length
            {
                arr2D[i][j] = message.substring(counterLetters, counterLetters+1);
                counterLetters++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void fill(String[][] arr2D,String cover)
    {
        int counterLetters = 0;

        for(int i =0;i<arr2D.length;i++) //arr.2D.length gives row length
        {
            for(int j = 0;j<arr2D[i].length;j++)//arr2D[].length gives column length
            {
                arr2D[i][j] = cover.substring(counterLetters, counterLetters+1);
                counterLetters++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void print2DArray(String[][] arr2D)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<arr2D.length;i++) //arr.2D.length gives row length
        {
            for(int j = 0;j<arr2D[i].length;j++)//arr2D[].length gives column length
            {
                System.out.print(arr2D[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is obviously a homework type question, and as such, you should always show us your best good-faith attempt at a solution, any solution, and then use it to ask a much more specific question. Why not do this as you've nothing to lose, and your question quality would have much to gain. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852). This information is valid whether or not the question is for homework or home work (self-study).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added what I have so far and tried to make my question more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is iterate over the length of the arrays and check if the element at a specific index in the cover array is `O`. If it is, then add the element from the message array to a string which will contain the full message:

```
// Assuming that the cover and message arrays are of type chars

String messageStr = "";
// Since the message and cover arrays should be the same length, it doesn't matter which one is used to get the length of the loop
for (int i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < messageArray[i].length; j++) {
        if (cover[i][j] == 'O') {
            messageStr += messageArray[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to implement this, how would I begin checking at a specific index? The cover starts at index [2][5] of the original message.

Comment: Instead of setting `i` and `j` to `0`, set them to the values you want them to be.

Comment: I wrote my answer before you posted your code, but now that you added code, it looks like you were on the right track. It seems that the only thing you don't do in your code is check the cover array elements for `O` and then add the corresponding message array character to the total message string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wasn't thinking straight when I commented earlier; was stressing out about the assignment. I finally got it working. Thanks again